# runtime too long for GC skew

Tags: rosalind

I'm currently working on a script that analyzes skew differences. Unfortunately, my problem is that when the length of the string increases, the runtime becomes too long and I can't seem to calculate my answer.

```
def SkewGC(file):
    countG = 0
    countC = 0
    diffGtoC = ""
    # first, we need to find number of G's.
    # the idea is, if G appears, we add it to the count.
    # We'll just do the same to each one.
    for pos in range(0,len(file)):
        if file[pos] == "G":
            countG = countG+1
        if file[pos] == "C":
            countC = countC+1
        diffGtoC = diffGtoC + str(countG-countC) + ","
    return diffGtoC.split(",")

SkewGCArray = SkewGC(data)
# This because I included extra "," at the end...
SkewGCArray = [int(i) for i in SkewGCArray[:len(SkewGCArray)-1]]

def min_locator(file):
    min_indices = ""
    for pos in range(0,len(file)):
        if file[pos] == min(file):
            min_indices = min_indices + str(pos) + " "
    return min_indices

print min_locator(SkewGCArray)
```

Essentially, this script calculates the number of G and C (corresponds to nucleotides in DNA), obtains differences at each position, and then I'm trying to find the indices of minimum. It works fine for low length of file (that's the input string) but when the length becomes large - even like 90000+, then my script runs but cannot resolve to an answer in reasonable time (~4-5 min).

Can anyone point to me what I could do to make it quicker? I've thought about whether it's better to say, obtain the difference (diffGtoC), set that as the minimum, and then re-calculate each difference until it sees something different during which I also replace the minimum value too.

But the concern I had that with this approach is on finding and retaining the indices of minimum. If I say, had an array with values:

[-4,-2,-5,-6,-5,-6]

I can see how changing the minimum value (-4 to -5 and then to -6) will be quicker in terms of algorithm runtime but how will I be able to maintain both -6's position? Not sure if this makes completely sense.

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions to improve the performance of your code:

```
diffGtoC = diffGtoC + str(countG-countC) + ","
    return diffGtoC.split(",")
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
diffGtoC = list()
diffGtoC.append(countG - countC)
```

Strings are immutable in Python, so you are generating a new string for every position which is not very efficient. Using a list will also save you the `str` and `int` conversions you are performing and the truncation of your list. You could also use [`pop()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm) to remove the last item of your list instead of generating a new one.

A really simple alternative would be to search for the minimum and only store the minimum value and its position. Then start iterating from the minimum position and see if you can find the minimum again and if yes append it to the first minimum position. Less data manipulation which saves time and memory.